# I can’t find Minecraft in files (apple tablet) after I deleted it due to bug issues

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

There was some bug in a texture pack, so when I clicked something it just crashed. I had to delete the app and download it back. But when I looked in my files to import my worlds and texture pack it wasn’t there.
Please, I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deleted the app, all the world data that was connected to the minecraft app. Therefore when you deleted the app all the data within it was also deleted. Your worlds were saved in the Minecraft folder in saves. Mojang did this so that you can easily access a singleplayer world if you are offline.

Comment: But I can’t it and need help

Comment: Like I need to import my texture packs and my world but I can’t find the Minecraft files